# Deque memory release

Tags: c++

I was reading somewhere about deque, I found a statement that the pop_back and pop_front just removes the element from the deque leaving behind the pointer that points to the element being removed.

```
int i=1;
std::deque<int> value:
while(1){ 
    if(value.size()>10){
        value.pop_front();
        value.shrink_to_fit();
    }
    value.push_back(i);
    i++;
}
```

I've used shrink_to_fit() just in case.

Now if the program is left running forever and we do hundreds and thousands of push and pop operations on deque, dont you think it will explode my ram ?
I hope I am not sounding funny.

Regards

Comment: Why don't you try it? Let it run for a day or two and see what happens.

Comment: There is no pointer to the element being removed. I think you need to learn from a different source.

Comment: Chances are you don't need to use the deque in the first place. Nor should you worry too much about container internals.

Comment: I have used deque because of the pop_front() method.

Comment: I wanted to implement circular queue, push_back and pop_front() in parallel after some size.

Comment: "_dont you think it will explode my ram?_" It shouldn't. Since the memory available to the application isn't equal to RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first understand what `shrink_to_fit` does.

`std::deque` is not a contiguous memory (unlike vectors) and uses blocks of memory. Which effectively means that it has multiple blocks of some size.

There might comes a situation where a block just contains 1 or 2 or some X amount of elements which prevent this blocks from being deleted.

`shrink_to_fit()` just helps in managing this scenario. It tries to move elements so as to allow block to be freed if possible

**Conclusion**

`shrink_to_fit()` has nothing to do with memory allocation and release and it may very well be useless to call for limited number of elements.

Comment: Well the scenario is, I dont know beforehand the size of deque, it will vary a lot until program execution ends.

Comment: you can use deque, but shrink_to_fit can at max help to clear 1 block. Even if you dont use it.. nothing will happen i.e your memory will not be exhausted as deque takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your container has at least 10 elements, your program is
 doing 1 push_back and 1 pop_front in each loop (infinite) iteration.

Memory usage should be stable, even if you don't use shrink_to_fit()

[EDIT] It is dependant on the implementation of std::deque
so memory usage might be a bit more than 10 elements but it should not grow dramatically in your case.

Comment: Yeah, my idea was to have 10 elements that I can use anywhere in the program before the program execution ends.